# How to download all iTunes Connect screenshots for an app?

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to make small changes to the screenshots for my iOS app and have misplaced the original files that I uploaded to iTunes Connect.

Was going to download them back to my computer, but the interface of iTunes Connect is acting up and only shows me the iPhone 6 screenshots, without any way to change to iPad and other phone sizes. That was also puzzling because it would also not allow me to upload any new screenshots for other screen sizes either :(.

I found [RMConnecter](https://github.com/realmacsoftware/RMConnecter) to help with the uploading process, but it still does not seem to have the ability to download existing screenshots.

Are there any other ways to get the screenshots that are already attached to my app? Do I have to wait for iTunes Connect to get back into shape, whenever that may be…

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [deliver](https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver) tool and do `deliver init` in a folder.

Basically you need open the terminal and do:

```
xcode-select --install
sudo gem install deliver
```

and then do `deliver init` in a folder.